# Is Contact Roles object available for community users in salesforce?

Tags: community

Is Contact Roles object available for community users in salesforce? I am not able to see contact roles object under account for community users. Anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As per this document https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/object_reference.pdf Contact role is not available for account in Communities.

> Special Access Rules
>
> **Customer Portal users can't access this object.**

You can create similar custom object and use trigger to achieve it.